# Using Swift, SwiftUI & Firebase as Database to create and authenticate a login

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

I have just recently started learning Xcode and I was following along a Youtube video and I've come across a problem with a user session check error when creating a login page.

Here is my authentication model to check wether a user is signed in or not

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
    
    init() {
        self.userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser
        
        print("DEBUG: User session is \(self.userSession)")
    }
    
    func login(withEmail email: String, password: String) {
        
        print("DEBUG: login with email \(email)")
        
    }
    
    func register(withEmail email: String, password: String, userame: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, occupation: String) {
        
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("debug: failed to register \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let user = result?.user else { return }
            self.userSession = user
            
            print("debug: registered user success")
            print("debug: user is \(self.userSession)")
            
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for it to run the app and show either login screen if a user is not logged in or the home screen of the app is there is a user logged in.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showMenu = false
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Group{
            
            if viewModel.userSession == nil {
                CompOwnerLogin()
            } else {
                mainInterfaceView
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    
    var mainInterfaceView: some View {
        
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading){
            MainTabView()
                .navigationBarHidden(showMenu)
            
            if showMenu{
                ZStack{
                    Color(.black)
                        .opacity(showMenu ? 0.25 : 0.0)
                }.onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                        showMenu = false
                    }
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
            
            SideMenuView()
                .frame(width: 165)
                .offset(x: showMenu ? 0: -150, y: 0)
                .background(showMenu ? Color.white : Color.clear)
        }
        .navigationTitle("Home")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading){
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                        showMenu.toggle()
                    }
                }label: {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            showMenu = false
        }
    }
}
```

Now in my console every time I run the app the User session is optional and never nil unless I force it to be nil. Not sure what is wrong because it runs logs new users if I force the session to be nil in order to see the login page.

Comment: Create a button to logoff from Firebase and see what happens - the current user should become nil. The session doesn't necessarily logoff when the app closes, Firebase is set to work also offline.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Would that matter if I deleted the user from my database manually in firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement an authorisation state listener that keeps track of whether a user is signed in or not:

```swift
func registerAuthStateHandler() {
    if authStateHandler == nil {
      authStateHandler = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        self.user = user
        self.authenticationState = user == nil ? .unauthenticated : .authenticated
        self.displayName = user?.email ?? ""
      }
    }
  }
```

See the [Getting Started with Firebase Authentication on Apple platforms](https://youtu.be/q-9lx7aSWcc) video to see how to implement this.

Comment: Nice function. Shame we couldn't see its implementation here. Instead we have to watch a YouTube video, which also recommends other YouTube videos and Twitter posts.

That's the Internet these days I guess.